# How do I make "ActiveXObject('SAPI.SpVoice')" work in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, activex, activexobject

How do I make `ActiveXObject('SAPI.SpVoice')` work in firefox?
firefox does not recognize the ActiveXObject function. Are there any alternatives for this?

Answer (score 1):

Firefox does not support ActiveX technology, you can try using plugins or extensions

Answer (score 1):

Because Firefox does not use ActiveX, you have to use a JavaScript substitute such as

http://www.masswerk.at/mespeak/

and

http://www.jtalkplugin.com/